# Make QJsonObject's key from timestamp

Tags: json, qt, qt5

Aim of my code is write log as json format with epoch timestamp.

I expect my code write log as below.

```
{234231412:{"user":"alex", "device":"HD-3432", "action":"connectin to server}}
```

Here is my code which failed to build.

```
void writeLog(const QJsonObject &jsonLog) {
    qint64 timestamp = QDateTime::currentSecsSinceEpoch();
    QString strTimestamp = QString::number(timestamp);
    QJsonObject jsonObj[strTimestamp] = jsonLog;
    QJsonDocument log(jsonObj);

    static QFile f(FireRest::logFile);
    if (!f.isOpen()) {
        f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
    }
    static QTextStream ts(&f);
    QString t;
    t.sprintf("%s\n", log.toString());

    ts << t << endl;

    QString fpo(logFile + QString(".old"));
    if (f.size() > MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE) {
        f.close();
        QFile::remove(fpo);
        QFile::rename(logFile, fpo);
    }
}
```

`QJsonObject jsonObj[strTimestamp] = jsonLog;` makes *size of array has non-integer type 'QString'*

`QJsonDocument log(jsonObj);` makes *variable has incomplete type 'QJsonDocument'*

How can I fix to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this line

```
QJsonObject jsonObj[strTimestamp] = jsonLog;
```

means you are creating an array of `QJsonObject`.

Try to create the instance of `QJsonObject` and then assign property `strTimestamp`

```
QJsonObject jsonObj;
jsonObj[strTimestamp] = jsonLog;
```

Comment: And add `#include <QJsonDocument>`, to fix the second error.